# Variable not functioning after adding dependent component in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular and I have two components. The first one is a navbar that has a search bar, so I put this code to send the content to my second component (home) and do the search:

html navbar:

```
<input class="form-control border-0 rounded-pill shadow-sm search-input " type="search" value="search" id="searchinput"  #searchinput (keyup.enter)="search(searchinput.value)">

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-white border-0 rounded-pill shadow-sm" type="button" (click)="search(searchinput.value)">
              <i class="material-icons">search</i>
</button>
```

component navbar:

```
@Output() searchEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  search(search : string) {
    this.searchEvent.emit(search);
  }
```

html home:

```
<app-navbar (searchEvent)="search($event)"></app-navbar>
```

component home:

```
  search(search : string) {
   ...logic code to make the search...
  }
```

And it works, but when I put <app-navbar (searchEvent)="search($event)"> in my HTML, my variables in the navbar stop working correctly. For example, I have a variable called "token", and when my user logs in, the token becomes true. I have a verification in my HTML to change the visual if the token is true or false, but it doesn't work anymore. It's weird, but if I remove the dependency <app-navbar (searchEvent)="search($event)"> from my HomeComponent, my HTML navbar can see the changes that happen again when the user logs in (token = true) or logs out (token = false).

html navbar:

```
<div *ngIf="!(token$ | async)" class="d-flex">
 ...buttons to log in and sing in...
</div>
<div *ngIf="(token$ | async)">
 ...buttons from user...
</div>
```

component navbar:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null){
      this.token$.next(false);
    }else{
      this.token$.next(true);
    }
  }


   private requestAut =  new AutRequestDto();
   logIn(email:string, password:string){ 
    this.requestAut .email = email;
    this.requestAut .password = password;
    this.userService.autenticarUsuario(this.requestAut).pipe(
      tap(
        (result: any) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem("token", result.token);
          this.token$.next(true);
          
          // location.reload();
        }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error.error.message);
        return of(error);
      })
    ).subscribe();
      
  }


  logout(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
    this.token$.next(false);
  }
```

If I press F5, the changes will be applied, or if I use location.reload();, but I'd like to see the changes in real-time instead of using location.reload(). Do you have any idea what could be happening? There are no errors in the console, and the code seems to be executing normally in debug mode.

I already tried using this.cdr.detectChanges() and this.cdr.markForCheck() in the login() method, but nothing works. I also tried using token sync instead of async, but that didn't help either.

I'm expecting that when the token becomes true in the success callback function in my component, my HTML will automatically update and reflect the change. It's strange that the logout works this way, but for the login, I need to press F5 to see the changes.

Comment: check errors in console and check if you have a variable "search" (or a template reference variable called "search") furthermore a function "search" in you home.component (in this case there're a conflict and the app crash)

Answer (score 0):

try changing your home html to messageEvent:

```
<app-navbar (messageEvent)="search($event)"></app-navbar>
```

and then change your home.ts to:

```
  search(search : any) {
    ...logic code to make the search...
  }
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand it, but I changed my @Output() searchEvent = new EventEmitter<string>(); to @Output() searchMessageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>(); so that I could implement what you suggested. However, it didn't work for me. Please let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: no, just change your html on your home page to what I wrote above. Don't change your typescript.

Comment: Right, but when I put it in my HTML, it shows this error in the $event: 'Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. I changed my 'search' method to receive an 'Event' type, but after doing so, my search stopped working, and the application cannot call the method anymore.

Comment: change your component home .ts to: `search(search : any)` (see edit above)